# Is there a way to pass data out of the .subscribe in my angular2 service?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I've got the following function in my AuthService:

```
getToken() {
  this.http.post('myAuthEndpoint', { credentials })
  .subscribe((res) => {
    const token = res.headers.get('Authorization')
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
  });
}
```

I want to return from `getToken()` the actual token value that I get back in the `.subscribe`.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Nope, that's the whole point of observables (and promises before them). The value you'd want to return is not necessarily available when the call finishes.

Comment: Is there a way I can refactor then to return the token in my getToken()?

Comment: No, there isn't. The process of getting the token is asynchronous. Instead you should return an observable (or convert it to a promise), return that and let the *caller* subscribe to it. See my advice to someone else with a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271214/how-to-get-a-global-http-get-request-for-use-everywhere?noredirect=1#comment69743655_41271214

Comment: Thanks.  The issue I'm facing is that because this is async, I have some other requests firing off which depend on the token, and since the token is undefined until getToken() completes, it fails

Comment: Then you need to use the other methods rxjs offers, like `map`, which allow you to chain async actions.

Comment: Thanks.  Please correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think I can use `map` because I'm getting headers back.  I am getting Authorization header

Comment: You are wrong, you can absolutely use it to extract the headers from the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do some other action when token is available you can do the following:

```
getToken() {
  return this.http.post('myAuthEndpoint', { credentials })
  .map((res) => {
    const token = res.headers.get('Authorization')
    return token;
  })
  .do((token) => {
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
  });
}

// some other part of app
authService.getToken()
  .switchMap((token) => {
    // perform any desired action
  })
  .subscribe((result) => ...);
```

But beware that in this case calling `getToken()` without subsequent `subscribe` won't do anything.

**Answer to comments**

You have two services one provides token and other consumes it:

```
export class AuthService {
  private tokenSource = new ReplaySubject(1);
  private token$ = this.tokenSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    return this.http.post('myAuthEndpoint', { credentials })
    .map((res) => {
      let token = res.headers.get('Authorization')
      return token;
    })
    .do((token) => {
      localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    })
    .subscribe(this.tokenSource);
  }

  getToken() {
    return this.token$;
  }
}

export class RecentPhotosService {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
    this.authService.getToken()
      .switchMap(token => {
        return this.getRecentPhotos(token);
      })
      .subscribe(photos => {...});
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sergey!  Do you think it is advisable to do this in the app.component and just propagate the key down to any components which need it for making HTTP requests?

Comment: @user1354934, I would rather put it into a service, like you did with `authService`. But there is a catch, if you use it as it is and subscribe to `getToken` multiple times it will do http call on every subscription! To avoid this you need to cache the result.

Comment: What would be the best way to do that?  Also, can you tell me if my reasoning is wrong?  I put the subscribe into app.component because that is the component that will load first and it loads my other router components.  Only the router components (parent components) have http calls they make in ngOnInit, so they can use the data I pass them.

Comment: What I don't understand about using the service is - how can I get that data without first subscribing to getToken somewhere?  For instance, I have a `recent-photos.service.ts` in which I've got a getRecentPhotos() that needs this key.  How can I use my AuthService inside this service?

Comment: @user1354934, Check the answer

Comment: Thanks.  This works but to be honest I don't really understand what is going on.  For now, I've got another way I figured out of doing this via using AuthGuard and calling the auth service there if there's no token.  However, I will study your solution as well because it is really cool.  Thanks